# Crash application on dismiss ViewController OS X (Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, dismiss, nsviewcontroller, osx-yosemite

It should be a decision on OS X Swift

Problem - application crashed on represent `NSViewController`

There have two `NSViewController` – the problem, when I do a transition between them - application closed with error on represent `NSViewControllers`.
There use the methods of presentViewController and dismissViewController.

Example project with problem here: [git@github.com:IgorCova/Freelance.git](http://git@github.com:IgorCova/Freelance.git)

How to reproduce the error (on Yosemite only):
1. I open first NSViewController
2. After I open second NSViewController
3. Next, go back to the first (dismiss second)
4. Then again trying to open a second NSViewController - in the end, the application crushes (But on El Capitan everything works without errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `SecondViewController`’s viewDidLoad() you register itself as an observer for "dismisSecondViewController" notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SecondViewController.dismisSelf),
                                                           name:"dismisSecondViewController",
                                                         object: nil)
```

The problem is that prior to 10.11 you have to *unregister* any observers before they get deallocated (i.e. removed from memory), otherwise NSNotificationCenter will continue to send messages to something that now occupies this deallocated memory region — it may be either garbage or some other object that doesn't respond to these messages. Since your view controllers clearly get deallocated when you switch them, this is your issue.

So the fix is easy: add the following `deinit` method to your `SecondViewController` class

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```